# How to solve this error after importing project in to my Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I am importing an Android project in to my eclipse after importing it's showing a red ! mark error on project folder so please help me how resolve these type of error an the project consists no other errors .

Comment: fix android properties or  also check android target !!!!

Comment: please search so properly before posting questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few days before i had same issue but there was a problem in libraries path . I think it is the problem with your project too . Please change the path Right Click to your project then follow:

Build path --> Configure Build Path -->java Build Path

Then remove your already present libraries & then add your libraries from the Current Location of those Libraries.

Comment: Yes i solved my issue using this procedure . thnx @ PhoneGap Developer

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps,

- Right Click on the project,
- Select Build Path
- Repair any missing library
- Clean the project

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your help now the problem is solved .............The error is gone and its running.

Comment: Good, actually its general problem ;)

Comment: Well you are new to Stack Overflow, so next time before asking a question just search for similar situation. Same question has been asked many times that's why you are getting downvotes.